# Sum columns mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have this collection

```
{a:0,b:1,c:1,d:1}
{a:1,b:1,c:0,d:1}
{a:1,b:1,c:0,d:1}
```

and I want this result with mapReduce

```
{id: any, A:2,B:3,C:1,D:3}
```

but I don't know how do it, I only can sum onde collumn
how i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `I only can sum onde collumn` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `emit` a common key for all the records, in the `map` function:

```
var map = function(){emit(1,this);}
```

The `reduce` function would calculate the sum and return the values.

```
var reduce = function(key,values){
var result = {};
values.forEach(function(i){
 Object.keys(i).forEach(function(key){
 if(result.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    result[key] = i[key]+result[key];
 }
 else{
    result[key] = i[key];
 }
})
})
return result;
}
```

Execute the map reduce:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(map,reduce,{ out: "out"})
```

If you knew the keys before hand, then you could easily aggregate the results, using just the `$group` stage in the pipeline.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":null,
         "a":{$sum:"$a"},
         "b":{$sum:"$b"},
         "c":{$sum:"$c"},
         "d":{$sum:"$d"}}}
])
```